# Mantain text style Qgis2web OL3

Tags: qgis, javascript, web-mapping, style, qgis2web

I created a map using Qgis with some labels on it. I stylized the label text making it bold and changing the font size, but when I export the map using OL3, all the changes were lost.

There is a way to keep those changes? Which file do I need to modify to set the label text bold?

I'm using Qgis2web v.2.22.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's meant to retain as many style aspects as it can. To change things manually open the folder `/styles` in your exported map. Open the file which has the relevant layer name in a text editor, and look for lines similar to these:

```
var text = new ol.style.Text({
    font: '13.325px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif',
    text: labelText,
    textBaseline: "middle",
    textAlign: textAlign,
    offsetX: offsetX,
    offsetY: offsetY,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(31, 120, 180, 1)'
    })
});
```

Change the settings you want (with reference to http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html), adding any CSS you want to the `font` property, and save the file.

Comment: If you were able to upload your project and layer files somewhere, I (or someone) could take a look to see why the text styles didn't come through.